# What does "beauty is only sin deep" mean?

Tags: meaning, short-stories, saki, reginald

In the short story, [Reginald's Choir Treat](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2830/2830-h/2830-h.htm), Saki writes:

> “You are really indecently vain of your appearance.  A good life is infinitely preferable to good looks."
>
> "You agree with me that the two are incompatible.  I always say beauty is only sin deep.”

What does "beauty is only sin deep" mean? Is Saki implying that sin is required to attain, or maintain, one's beauty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a play on "[beauty is only skin deep](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/59200.html)" -- the second character agrees about the vanity but is willing to accept the sin for the beauty.